# creating a new array every 10 items added

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code that shows the items added in the producs table in the database and i want to make it every 10 items creating a new array so that it won't be a long list of items.

```
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $dynamicList .= '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
        <tr>
          <td width="10%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpeg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="93" height="102" border="1" /></a></td>
          <td width="90%" valign="top">' . $product_name . '<br />
            €' . $price . '<br />
            <a class="provoli" href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">Προβολή Λεπτομεριών</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>';
```

Comment: look up stuff with "pagination" and the sql 'LIMIT' and 'OFFSET'

Comment: "So it won't be a long list of items" has so many reasons behind it. It would help if you can explain the reasoning - then we can give a valid answer. (You can "limit" the results through SQL if you're doing pagination, you can have an array of arrays but probably don't need to as you can post-process in groups of 10 etc.)

Comment: Switch to Mysqli or PDO, then decide whether you want to make use of an array (e.g. via `array_chunk`) or use a `LimitIterator` or just make use of SQL's `LIMIT` - depending on your needs. Apart from all that your question is not very concrete. The code also mixes fetching data and outputting it - you should divide that into two parts.

Comment: Also it might be of interest to fetch the whole list and implement the paging on the client side using javascript. That way the database has to be queried only once and the user experience is much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Your code-style could use some work, as it is not very pretty, but, to make this work, you could try putting your list in an array.

This requires two steps, the first is keeping record of an index. The second is adding the values to your new array.

```
$index = 0;
while(<your condition>) {
    $index++;
    <more code>
    $list[((int)$index/10)] .= <string>
}
```

A better way is to implement this when printing the array with all your items. But I don't know how you're implementing this further.

Comment: What about when $index >=10 ... collision!

Comment: I've once again replaced a modulus with a division! Thanks.
(Although it would work, just in a very interesting order ;))

Comment: Why not just use $list[] = $string? You dont have to specify a numeric array index at all. Also I dont understand the string concatenation you are using

Comment: I have tried to change as little as possible to the code-style used by the OP, and the question was to 'create a new array' so it wont be one big list. This splits the list per 10, in a new array.